# Creating feature layer in InMemoryWorkspace using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.4, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I'm writing a WPF application, in C#, using ArcObjects.

I have an ESRI.ArcGIS.Controls.AxMapControl on my form, and I'm trying to draw some point features on top of it, in code.

It's been suggested that I create a point feature layer, in an InMemoryWorkspace, and add that to the map.

I've not been able to find any decent examples of how to do this, online.

Can anyone give me an example of how to create a point feature layer, in an InMemoryWorkspace, or point me to an example elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that you want to create a featurelayer *in* an InMemoryWorkspace.  More likely you want to store the data used by a featurelayer in memory instead of in a file geodatabase, shapefile, or sde workspace.

Search for `InMemoryWorkspaceFactory` and you should be able to find samples such as [this](http://www.databasesql.info/article/3864231887/).

Comment: What I want is the ability to place markers and labels on the map at set locations, at a fixed size, independent of the zoom level of the map. And I need the locations of these markers and labels is determined by code, rather than in a geodatabase, shapefile, etc.

Comment: Typically this is done using `IGraphicsContainer` to add `IMarkerElement`s to the map.  See "Add Graphic to Map" [here](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/dotnet/ec9c3bf9-1bae-4d56-9ae6-e439dbd0f18f.htm#addArcGISSnippetsFunctionalityToTheDrawGraphicLineTool)

Comment: I tried that, but the markers scaled to the map - they drew at a fixed size relative to the map, and scaled in size as the map zoomed in and out.

Comment: Are you saying the dimensions in pixels for the symbol changed, or was constant?

Comment: I'm saying that the dimension in map units is constant. If I draw with a size of 25 on a foot-dimensioned map, the marker is 25 feet across, which renders as a varying number of pixels depending upon the map zoom level.  What I want is a constant number of pixels independent of map zoom. I was told this wasn't possible with IGraphicsContainer, and I needed to create a FeatureLayer with ScaleSymbols turned off.

Comment: It's easy to create a feature layer (IFeatureLayer) and add it to the map, you don't need to store it anywhere, if you only want to copy certain features *then* copy to your InMemoryWorkspace and create a layer from that. Just remember if you turn *on* scale symbols you *must* also set the reference scale for the map IMap::ReferenceScale or the ScaleSymbols property is meaningless.